# SQL SERVER count distinct using Offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

With this query:

```
SELECT ID,Make,Model 
FROM cars 
WHERE active='true'  
ORDER BY make ASC, model ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

I got this result:

```
ID          Make         Model
26800911    AIXAM       CROSSLINE
26796643    AIXAM       PREMIUM
26700448    ALFA ROMEO  145
26796420    ALFA ROMEO  147
26480721    ALFA ROMEO  147
```

How to write query to get from this result Count of Each make?
So i need to have AIXAm = 2, Alfa Romeo = 3

Thoose one return all result without Offset Limit

```
SELECT make,SUM(CASE WHEN active='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM cars 
WHERE active='true' 
GROUP BY make 
ORDER BY make ASC;
```

AND

```
SELECT make,Count(make) 
FROM cars 
WHERE active='true' 
GROUP BY make 
ORDER BY make ASC;
```

AND

```
SELECT TOP 5 make,SUM(CASE WHEN active='true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM cars 
WHERE active='true' 
GROUP BY make 
ORDER BY make ASC;
```

All return not what i need

```
AIXAM       2
ALFA ROMEO  106
ALPINA      1
AUDI        686
BMW         557
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with a subquery:

```
SELECT q.Make, Count(q.ID)
FROM
(
SELECT ID,Make,Model 
FROM cars 
WHERE active='true'  
ORDER BY make ASC, model ASC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
) AS q
GROUP BY q.make
ORDER BY q.make ASC;
```

Comment: Yes! that realy what i need Thanks